# Reading all files in a particular directory exclude some with particular regex in python

Tags: python, file, parsing

Need to read all files(with some exclusions) in particular directory parse the content of each and write to other file.

While I want to exclude some file based on some regex.I want to do so in python. Can anyone describe how to do that in python?

Comment: does the directory just have files, or also other sub-directories with other files you need to read through?

Comment: It just have files. No subdirectories.

Comment: You should provide an example of what you tried and what isn't working. The [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html) [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) (hint: `os.walk` and `glob`) is so easy to consult and it's really good!

Answer (score 0):

Concept script:

```
import re, os
files = os.listdir(path) # list of file returned
test = re.compile(...) # your reg expression
sublist = [f for f in files if test.search(f)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `glob.glob()`

```
import glob
glob.glob(path)
```

`path` can contain *unix wildcards*, not regex though.